# Offensive Rebound Rate correlation to wins

Tags: statistics, nba

How many more games should a team expect to win if its offensive rebound rate increases from 25% to 27%, all else equal?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's primarily a mathematics question, not sporting

Comment: @TrueDub Note that we have questions on [`sabermetrics`](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sabermetrics), which is mathematical analysis of statistics. Given the answer from Joe, this looks no different.

Answer (score 2):

It's unlikely offensive rebound rate would increase by two points all else equal; however, given that, a two point increase in the rate is roughly a standard deviation (probably a bit under).  One standard deviation is worth [about 2.56 additional wins](http://www.canishoopus.com/2013/9/13/4724112/offensive-rebounds-what-good) according to one measure, so your two point increase in ORR is probably worth two to two and a half wins.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  i just need to figure out the SD from the population.